# How to test methods with attributes with asp.net core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

My project is an ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application.

How can I test if my own written attribute is working fine by calling a method containing the attribute?

For example:

Attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ValidateUserLoggedInAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
  {
     var controller = (BaseController)context.Controller;
     if (!controller.UserRepository.IsUserLoggedIn)
     {
        var routeValueForLogin = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Login", controller = "Home", area = "" });
        context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValueForLogin);
     }
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
[ValidateUserLoggedIn]
public IActionResult Start()
{
    ...
}
```

Test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    // Act
    var result = this.controllerUnderTest.Start() as RedirectToRouteResult;

    // Assert
     Assert.IsNotNull(result);
     Assert.IsFalse(result.Permanent);

     var routeValues = result.RouteValues;

     const string ControllerKey = "controller";
     Assert.IsTrue(routeValues.ContainsKey(ControllerKey));
     Assert.AreEqual("Home", routeValues[ControllerKey]);

     const string ActionKey = "action";
     Assert.IsTrue(routeValues.ContainsKey(ActionKey));
     Assert.AreEqual("Login", routeValues[ActionKey]);
}
```

I have already written a test only for the attribute by creating an `ActionExecutingContext`, but I also want to test it for the controller method.

Comment: That would require an integration test where you send an actual request either in-memory test server or running site and then verify expected behavior https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing

Comment: Better to test the method and test the attribute separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would require an integration test where you send an actual request either with an in-memory test server or running site and then verify expected behavior.

Refer to [Integration testing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing)

You you have already tested the attribute in isolation with a unit test, it stands to reason that it would behave as expected in an integration and in production provided the test covered expected behavior